# OutOfMemory Error when trying to convert string list to long list using type converter in room db

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room, typeconverter

I am getting the following error when I am using a type converter to convert a string array to long array and saving it into the room database.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2064 byte allocation with 1782896 free bytes and 1741KB until OOM, target footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
   at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.<init>(JsonReader.java:231)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonReader(Gson.java:767)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:896)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
   at com.tigerit.signalmessenger.database.converters.DataConverter.toLongList(DataConverter.java:20)
   at com.tigerit.signalmessenger.database.daos.ConversationDao_Impl$50.call(ConversationDao_Impl.java:2063)
   at com.tigerit.signalmessenger.database.daos.ConversationDao_Impl$50.call(ConversationDao_Impl.java:1903)
   at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Below is my type converter code,

```
class DataConverter {
@TypeConverter
fun fromLongList(value: List<Long>): String {
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<Long>>() {}.type
    return gson.toJson(value, type)
}

@TypeConverter
fun toLongList(value: String): List<Long> {
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<Long>>() {}.type
    return gson.fromJson(value, type)
}
}
```

When the type converter is trying to convert the string list from the DB to long list then the error happens. The string list can contain upto 200 items like the following,

> [56,29,104,126,13,115,66,127,20,2,101,42,49,48,114,9,23,64,108,110,61,84,62,50,97,120,26,96,67,59,65,111,113,80,38,58,89,70,98,125,75,72,8,24,105,119,25,69,14,35,88,11,91,15,92,57,33,36,129,44,10,79,12,106,22,27,81,34,41,85,18,32,21,37,94,68,78,53,132,6,122,73,109,43,4,118,102,74,40,133,5,117,16,130,86,131,1,128,31,63,3,46,99,30,19,39]

Comment: It's not about this operation.  You were only trying to allocate 2 KB there.  It's about all the memory used throughout your app.  Use LeakCanary or heap dumps to find any memory leaks and where you're memory is actually being used so you can optimize/fix leaks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error)